# split string and put words into an array

Tags: arrays, c, string, split

I am working on a function which allows to split a character string and to place each word in an array. the last cell of the array must return a null. the separator character must be a space, a tabulation or a new line.

*code :*

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int is_sep(char c) // function return 1 if char is sep, and 0 if not.
{
    if (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n')
        return (1);
    return (0);
}

int nb_word(char *str) // function that counts the number of words
{
    int i;
    int word;

    i = -1;
    word = 0;
    while (str[++i])
        if ((is_sep(str[i]) == 0 && is_sep(str[i + 1]) == 1) // if char != sep & char + 1 = sep || char != sep & char + 1 = \0. so, we are on a word.
        || (is_sep(str[i]) == 0 && str[i + 1] == '\0'))
            word++;
    return (word);
}

void    ft_strcpy(char *dest, char *src) // function copying word in array.
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (src[i])
    {
        dest[i] = src[i];
        i++;
    }
    dest[i] = '\0';
}  

void put_tab(char *str, char **tab) // function who malloc the letters numbers of the word
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int word;

    i = -1;
    j = 0;
    word = 0;
    while (str[++i]) // we run the string
    {
        if (is_sep(str[i]) == 1) // if the char is sep, we increment
            i++;
        else
        {
            while (is_sep(str[i + j]) == 0) // while the char is not sep, we increment j (j will be the size of the word)
                j++;
            tab[word] = malloc(sizeof(int) * j + 1); // we malloc the size of the word
            ft_strcpy(tab[word], str + i); // copying
            word++;
            i = j + 1;
        }
    }
}

char **ft_split(char *str)
{
    char **tab;
    int word;

    word = nb_word(str); // word take the value of the number total of words
    if (!(tab = malloc(sizeof(char) * word + 1))) // malloc size of array (+ 1 for the NULL end)
        return (NULL);
    put_in_tab(str, tab);
    tab[word + 1] = NULL; // put our NULL
    return (tab);
}

#include <stdio.h>

int        main(void)
{
    char **arr;

     char *words = "   Hello,   World\t test!  ";
     arr = ft_split(words);
     printf("%s\n", arr[0]);
     printf("%s\n", arr[1]);
     printf("%s\n", arr[2]);
     printf("%s\n", arr[3]);
 }
```

*this is a display :*

```
arr[0] =
arr[1] = `
arr[2] = World   test!
arr[3] = rld     test!
```

*The display must will be :*

```
arr[0] = Hello,
arr[1] = world
arr[2] = tets!
arr[3] = NULL
```

thanks for your help. And sorry for my english..

Comment: `sizeof(char) * word + 1` should be `sizeof(char*) * (word + 1)`

Comment: `sizeof(int) * j + 1` should be `sizeof(char) * (j + 1)`

Comment: When you call `malloc()`, the type in `sizeof()` should be the same as the pointer you're assigning to, but with one less `*`.

Comment: And you need parenthese around `word + 1` because of default operator precedence.

Comment: You could make your `nb_word` function much easier to read and more compact by using `strcspn` in a loop.